# I need some help with a Java recursion problems

Tags: java, loops, recursion

This is my first problem:

```
gcd(x,y)
  if (x < y)
    gcd(y,x)
  else
    if (y = 0)
      return x
    else
      return gcd(y, x mod y)
```

This is my second problem:

```
public static int Test2(int x, int y) {
  if (x > y) {
    return 10;
  } else {
    return Test2(x-5, y+5) + 5;
  }
}
```

The question is: What is returned for `gcd(84, 21)`?

- a. 84
- b. 21
- c. 3   (This is the correct answer)
- d. 10

X equals 84 and y equals 21. So I run them through the Algorithm class. 84 is not less than 21 so I skip that if statement. 84 is not equal so I skip that statement. I go to return gcd(y, x mod y). I don’t understand what is mod and how do you figure out what it means?

Second problem!
Question: What is returned for `Test2(18,5)`?

- A. 5
- B. 10
  I choose ten , because x is greater than y and when processed to the if statement. It returns a value of ten. The if statements does run anything but the return statement.
- C. 15 The answer is 15.
- D. 20

Comment: In the first posting: if (y == 0) ==: comparison, =: assignment. And (x % y), not (x mod y), for Java-code. Well - the method header is complete pseudo code, not Java. However, my impression is, that answer b is correct for question 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mod` is the [modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) function. It's the rest when when you divide two integers. For example,

```
1 mod 3 = 1
2 mod 3 = 2
3 mod 3 = 0
4 mod 3 = 1
10 mod 4 = 2
```

10 is the correct answer for the second question, your argument is correct.

Answer (score 0):

`x mod y` is not valid Java, `x % y` is and it means modulo; that what if left after an integer division of x by y.

Btw, what do you mean with `this is the answer` and  `the answer is 15`? Better to think the problem through and explain your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

The [modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) operator returns the remainder of a divison operation. e.g. `3 mod 2 = 1` since 1 is the remainder. `%` is commonly used as the symbol for mod. In this example `84 mod 21` equals 0 since 21 divides evenly into 84 four times.